# Can I get \addlegendimage to print a custom legend draw/line style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

### Problem

I've created a figure where I plot a line and add a node at the beginning of the line and a diamond at the end of the line by using `node`s in my `\addplot` command like so:

```
\addplot[red,no markers,] {x} node[pos=0,circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {} node[pos=1,diamond,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {};
```

I was wondering if there's a way to include a line that looks like this in the legend as well.

I know I can use `\addlegendimage` to generate custom legend entries, and I know I can use `\addlegendimage{red,->}` to generate a custom legend entry that's a red arrow, but I don't know how to create a legend entry that's a line with a filled circle at the start and a filled diamond at the end. The following doesn't work, so this is where I got stuck:

```
\addlegendimage{\draw[red,] (0,0) node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {} -- (1,0) node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {};}
```

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    legend entries={A,B,C,D},
    legend pos=north west,
  ]

    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=*}
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=diamond*}
    \addlegendimage{no markers,red}
    \addlegendimage{red,->}

    \addplot[red,no markers,] {x} node[pos=0,circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {} node[pos=1,diamond,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new legend image style:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/line legend with two nodes/.style 2 args={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1,no markers]
        plot coordinates {
        (0cm,0cm)
        (0.3cm,0cm)
        (0.6cm,0cm)
      }
      node[pos=0,#1]{}
      node[#2]{};%
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}% current version is 1.13

\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/line legend with two nodes/.style 2 args={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw[##1,no markers]
        plot coordinates {
        (0cm,0cm)
        (0.3cm,0cm)
        (0.6cm,0cm)
      }
      node[pos=0,#1]{}
      node[#2]{};%
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    legend entries={A,B,C,D},
    legend pos=north west,
  ]

    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=*}
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=diamond*}
    \addlegendimage{no markers,red}
    \addlegendimage{
      line legend with two nodes={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}{diamond,fill,inner sep=1pt},
      red}

    \addplot[red,no markers,] {x} 
      node[pos=0,circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {} 
      node[diamond,fill=red,inner sep=2pt,] {};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what ##1 means? I understand that it allows something to become a parameter after the initial macro is expanded, but what becomes the parameter in this case?